# Incomplete formula for the glm negative binomial

Tags: generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution, lsmeans

My data is about the number of insects that go to treatment 1 or treatment 2, and I have the factor `place`, with four levels (places). Each place has a treatment and a control.
How can I know the preferences of insects in visiting treatment 1 or 2, adding the factor place? I know is a GLM.NB, but I don't know how to add this factor. Thanks

Comment: Is 'treatment 2' the same as the control? Furthermore, please clarify what you mean by _How can I know the preferences of insects in visiting treatment 1 or 2, adding the factor place?_

Comment: treatment 1 is flowers and treatment 2 is the control. i just want to know if the insects goes more to the control or to the treatment. thanks

Comment: I'd start from a model with marginal effects for treatment and place as well as their interaction and then run anova on the three models.

Comment: I used this formule: 
model4 <- glm.nb (TA$Amali ~ TA$Trat + (1|TA$Bloque) + (1|TA$Muestreo))

Amali is the name if the insect
Trat is (flowers or control)
Bloque (the place)
Muestreo (the date of colecta)

Comment: If you are using `R`, Be aware that `glm.nb` cannot handle random effects.

Comment: In addition, if you have random effects, it means that you have repeated measures, which you didn't mention in your post. If so, then consider editing your post by adding a full description of your data.

Comment: If there are only 4 `place` values then you are probably better off treating it as a fixed effect. You probably also shouldn't treat the date of collection as a random-effect term; it's usually better to model time directly in some way. Please edit your question to provide more details on your data, in particular how many collection times there were and if all `places` had the same collection times.